# Shell Script While Loop and Perl Printing Extra Line

Tags: perl, shell, loops, while-loop

I modified a script which a poster gave me from another board to better suit my needs. InputConfig.txt contains directories to find files in, the inbound file age (second column) and the outbound file age (third column). These inbound/outbound numbers for each directory don't have to be the same, I just made them so. Most important is VI and AB directories have specific age to check against, everything else uses the generic 30 minutes.

Perl statement purpose is to capture the timestamp of each file found. The problem is the `printf` is putting an extra line because the while loop is reading 3 lines but I only need the 2 lines (or however many) to print.

I don't know Perl well enough to fix it - if the problem is with Perl.

Appreciate the help.

InputConfig.txt

```
/home/MF/NA/CD 30 30
/home/MF/NA/CD/VI 10 10
/home/MF/NA/CD/AB 15 15
```

Script

```
#!/bin/ksh

VI=*/CD/VI/*
AB=*/CD/AB/*

cat InputConfig.txt | while read DIR IT OT; do
TS=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/inbound/*" -mmin "+${IT}" ! -path "${VI}" ! -path "${AB}")
TS=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/outbound/*.done" -mmin "+${OT}")
TS=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/inbound/*" -mmin +"${IT}")
perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $ARGV[0], (stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]);' "$TS" 
done
```

Output:

```
,0
/home/MF/NA/CD/VI/inbound/vis,1492716168
/home/MF/NA/CD/AB/inbound/abc,1492716485
```

Desired Output

```
/home/MF/NA/CD/VI/inbound/vis,1492716168
/home/MF/NA/CD/AB/inbound/abc,1492716485
```

Comment: It seems that in the first iteration of your loop `$TS` is empty? So output from `perl -e` is `",0"`... Also, why do you expect two lines of output when `InputConfig.txt` has 3 lines

Comment: You have three lines of inputs, and you ask `perl` to print a line for each of those...  Are you simply missing `if length($ARGV[0])`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I expect 2 lines of output because those are the files which 'find' found. The first line is not relevant to me.

Comment: @ikegami I want Perl to print lines for only files which were found. I understand it will print 3 lines because of the input but is there a way to make it only print for what the find command returned?

Comment: @ocbit Please show exactly the content of the `find` command. For example run  `echo "$TS"` before the `perl -e`

Comment: Simply don't understands. Here are 3x assignments `TS=$(..)` in row, so the only last one will be used. What's the point of the first two find?

Comment: @ocbit A guess would be that find does not return any results for the first line in `InputConfig.txt` then the suggestion by @ikegami should work

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yep makes sense. How would that check for length look like?

Comment: @ocbit `perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $ARGV[0], (stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]) if length($ARGV[0])' "$TS"`.. But what if `find` returns more than one result?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Didn't think about that. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ocbit Assuming filenames does not contain newlines, you can try this: `perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $_, (stat $_)[9]) for split "\n", $ARGV[0]' "$TS"`.. (Now you can even skip the `"if length(...)"` part)

Comment: In that case, `printf '%s' "$TS" | perl -nle'printf("%s,%d\n", $_, (stat $_)[9])'` would be better. The next step would be to remove `$TS` completely.   ...which is where the two posted answers went.

Answer (score 3):

The script has many problems:

- it assigns 3x in row the `TS` variable, so, only the last one will be used. The first two runs of the `find` is pointless - so probably you want achieve something else.
- youre getting the `mtime` using `perl`. It is cool idea if you will read the filenames from the `stdin` and not starting perl X times. In such case will be faster to use the `stat` shell command - with other words, you want read the filenames from the `stdin`.
- **always** use `read -r` (unless you know why do not want the `-r`) :)
- useless use of `cat`. Just redirect the whole loop input from a file

So, the script could probably looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh

VI=*/CD/VI/*
AB=*/CD/AB/*

while read -r DIR IT OT; do
    find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/inbound/*" -mmin "+${IT}" ! -path "${VI}" ! -path "${AB}" -print
    find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/outbound/*.done" -mmin "+${OT}" -print
    find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/inbound/*" -mmin +"${IT}" -print
done < InputConfig.txt | perl -lne 'printf "%s,%d\n", $_, (stat($_))[9];'
```

This is more `ksh` and/or `shell` question as `perl`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood, you want to use perl to display the name and the size of the files found by previous find commands. Something like that should work:

```
#!/bin/ksh

VI=*/CD/VI/*
AB=*/CD/AB/*

cat InputConfig.txt | while read DIR IT OT; do
(find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/inbound/*" -mmin "+${IT}" ! -path "${VI}" ! -path "${AB}" ;
find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/*/outbound/*.done" -mmin "+${OT}" ;
find "${DIR}" -type f -path "${DIR}/inbound/*" -mmin +"${IT}") |
xargs -l perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $ARGV[0], (stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]);'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input but I went back to my original `if-else` method of script since my TIBCO project from which I am calling the script was not liking the output format.

My script, invoked like `./CDFindFiles /home/NA/CD/`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

FOLDER=$1
VI=*/CD/VI/inbound
AB=*/CD/AB/inbound

find "$FOLDER" -type f -path "${FOLDER}*/inbound/*" -o -path "${FOLDER}*/outbound/*.done" | while read line;
 do
  MODTIME=$(perl -e 'printf "%d\n",(-M shift)*24*60' "$line")
  if [[ "$line" == *"$VI"* && "$MODTIME" -gt 90 || "$line" == *"$AB"* && "$MODTIME" -gt 180 ]]; then
   perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $ARGV[0], (stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]);' "$line"
  elif [[ "$line" != *"$VI"* && "$line" != *"$AB"* &&  "$MODTIME" -gt 30 ]]; then
    perl -e 'printf("%s,%d\n", $ARGV[0], (stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]);' "$line"
   fi
 done
```